# How to import trusted certificate or keystore in java keystore of Kudu(Azure)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I have one java application deployed in Azure web app, which interacts with third party application which is SSL enabled. I want to import java key store or certificate of the other application in azure web app.

Can someone please help in importing the certificate in azure web app so that my application can trust the third party application.

Answer (score 1):

The App Service Environment(ASE) is a deployment of the Azure App Service that runs within your Azure Virtual Network(VNet). The ASE is a single tenant system. Because it is single tenant, there are some features available only with an ASE that are not available in the multi-tenant App Service.

**Private client certificate**

A common use case is to configure your app as a client in a client-server model. If you secure your server with a private CA certificate, you will need to upload the client certificate to your app. The following instructions will load certificates to the truststore of the workers that your app is running on. If you load the certificate to one app, you can use it with your other apps in the same App Service plan without uploading the certificate again.

To upload the certificate to your app in your ASE:

1. Generate a .cer file for your certificate.
2. Go to the app that needs the certificate in the Azure portal
3. Go to SSL settings in the app. Click Upload Certificate. Select Public. Select Local Machine. Provide a name. Browse and select your .cer file. Select upload.
4. Copy the thumbprint.
5. Go to Application Settings. Create an App Setting WEBSITE_LOAD_ROOT_CERTIFICATES with the thumbprint as the value. If you have multiple certificates, you can put them in the same setting separated by commas and no whitespace like
   `84EC242A4EC7957817B8E48913E50953552DAFA6,6A5C65DC9247F762FE17BF8D4906E04FE6B31819`

The certificate will be available by all the apps in the same app service plan as the app, which configured that setting. If you need it to be available for apps in a different App Service plan, you will need to repeat the App Setting operation in an app in that App Service plan. To check that the certificate is set, go to the Kudu console and issue the following command in the PowerShell debug console:

`dir cert:\localmachine\root`

To perform testing, you can create a self signed certificate and generate a .cer file with the following PowerShell:

```
$certificate = New-SelfSignedCertificate -certstorelocation cert:\localmachine\my -dnsname "*.internal-contoso.com","*.scm.internal-contoso.com

$certThumbprint = "cert:\localMachine\my\" + $certificate.Thumbprint
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String "CHANGETHISPASSWORD" -Force -AsPlainText

$fileName = "exportedcert.cer"
export-certificate -Cert $certThumbprint -FilePath $fileName -Type CERT
```

Source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/environment/certificates#private-client-certificate